# Django Template System: How to call a parent block many times and fill it's content partially?

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to use a constant fragment in my menu that centers content of a child element:

```
<table height='100%' cellpadding='0px' cellspacing='0px'>
    <tr>
            <td valign='middle'>                
                {# place here child content #}                      
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is: I want to have an only html fragment **...table height='...** in a parent template according to DRY principle. There are many children that placed into the fragment (where comment).

How could I call the *table* block in my child template *many times* and place child html where comment?

Comment: You can try to use `{% include template.html %}`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! But it's impossible to pass nested child content.

Comment: Maybe use another way to align content that contain only one additional block through `display: table-cell`? http://cssing.org.ua/2005/07/14/vertical-align-middle/ for example.

Comment: @Deadly Great! But this does not work for IE properly.

Comment: @sergzach for IE6-7 you can use css-exprations and it's will works well everewhere. Full solution http://cssing.org.ua/2007/04/26/another-css-valign-method/

Comment: @Deadly I think that Javascript in css is not *clear* idea. But in any case thank you!

Comment: @sergzach this is the best solution at this moment, trust me :)

Comment: @Deadly What if javascript disabled in browser? I mean if we have a deal with css we don't care about Javascript and that great because Javascript is not technology to 'fix' markup.

Comment: @Deadly And the most significant minus of the approach that we must support correct markup for IE especially. It's not attractive because some sites change rather frequently and there are browsers other than IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I see is to create a simple custom tag *centervert*.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.tag
def centervert(parser, token):
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endcentervert',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return CenterVertNode(nodelist)

class CenterVertNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist):
        self.nodelist = nodelist
    def render(self, context):
        html = self.nodelist.render(context)
        return "<table cellpadding='0px' cellspacing='0px'><tr><td valign='center'>{0}</td></tr></table>".format( html )
```

And then in template use it:

```
{% centervert %}
  {# place here child content #} 
{% endcentervert %}
```